# GWMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration - Display Description and IP Address but only IPV4 (Exclude IPV6)

Tags: powershell, wmi-query, get-wmiobject

relatively new to Powershell.

I'm trying to output the Description and IPAddress values from the following code, without it outputing the IPV6 addresses with it.

I want the Description and the IPAddress values, I've managed to get it to output just IPV4 by doing Select -Expand IPAddress and a Like command, but I want the description to, when I try to add Description via select it just breaks the entire thing.

Below is as close as I've come, shows me Description + IP Address, but I want to hide the IPV6 to keep it neat.

```
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $endpointip |
             Where { $_.IPAddress -notlike '*::*'  } | Where {$_.Description -like '*GbE*' -or $_.Description -like '*Ethernet*' -or $_.Description -like '*Wi-Fi*'-or $_.Description -like '*Wireless*' -or $_.Description -like '*Cisco*'}| # filter the objects where an address actually exists
                             Select Description, IPAddress| Out-String # retrieve only the property *value*
```

Also tried it

```
$_.IPAddress -like '*.*.*'
```

However that just outputs like the below, I don't want the IPV6 Addresses

```
`Description                                                                      IPAddress                                                          
-----------                                                                      ---------                                                          
Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz                                                 {192.168.0.16, fe80::50d0:fda6:44ee:237d}                          
Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller                                                                                                                  
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter                                                                                                              
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter                                                                                                              
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64 {x.x.x.x, xxxx::xxxx:xxxxx:xxxx, xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx}
Realtek USB GbE Family Controller `
```

Or like this

```
Description                                                                      IPAddress                                                          
-----------                                                                      ---------                                                          
Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz                                                 {192.168.0.16, fe80::50d0:fda6:44ee:237d}                          
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64 {xx.xx.xx.xx, xxxx::xxxx:xxxxx:xxxx, xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to filter by is working as it's suppose to, in regard to how PowerShell "*thinks*". `*.*.*` will get the objects that have a value in `IPAddress` matching `*.*.*`, but it's not excluding the other values. The immediate fix would be using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) to extract that IP address:

```
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $endpointip | 
    Where {$_.Description -like '*GbE*' -or $_.Description -like '*Ethernet*' -or $_.Description -like '*Wi-Fi*'-or $_.Description -like '*Wireless*' -or $_.Description -like '*Cisco*'} | 
    Select Description, @{
        Name = 'IPAddress'
        Expression = { $_.IPAddress | Select -First 1}
    }
```

Here, you tell it to select just the first object value in `IPAddress` which is *almost* always the IPv4 Address.

- You can also use a filter against it to ensure that IP Address is matched using `$_.IPAddress | ? { $_ -like '*.*' }` instead.

Without knowing your PS version, `Get-CimInstance` superseded `Get-WMIObject` as of PS 3.0+ where it's not supported in PS core either.

Comment: Thank you very much Abraham 

I included the code you submitted and added a where at the start.
Where { $_.IPAddress -like '*.*'}

This outputs just as I want it now, many thanks

Comment: Regarding the Get-CimInstance I wasn't aware of that either, I tried to update the gwmi's to it, however got errors regarding WINRM, happy to stay with the gwmi for the use purpose